# Laravel 5.7 Auth::loginUsingId() not working after CSRF token generated

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, csrf-protection, laravel-5.7

I am trying to auto-login user on step-2 of registration steps. After successful insert into db i am using `Auth::loginUsingId($user_id)` to auto-login user using ajax. 
I am always submitting `CSRF` token on each steps.

Now the problem is after successful login `CSRF` token get generated and `Auth::user()` gets blank on step 3

Also before and after login `CSRF` is different.

Comment: upload code dear

Comment: on step2 using `Auth::loginUsingId($user_id);` to auto-login user and on step 3 using `$user = Auth::user();` to get user session which is blank

Comment: have you tried this `$user = Auth::User()->$user_id;` ?

Comment: `Auth::User()` this object is blank then how it will give `->user_id`?

Comment: I mean to say you need to pick the user with the login id as well because the session is started for that particular user.

Comment: But it would be really nice to use laravel's own auth, and without calling ajax function. If you are doing this with Ajax then later it will give you 302 status error.

Comment: and also you are generating token in each step, so it means you changing the session, which make it confusing for compiler

Answer (score 2):

First of all, csrf token is required when using non-GET request, so if in your case using GET request seems reasonable you can use it.

Otherwise, in step 2 you should return new CSRF token for example like this:

```
Auth::loginUsingId($user_id);

return response()->json(['csrf_token' => csrf_token()];
```

and then in step 3 use this new token you got from Step 2 response.

Comment: Hey Thanks for your response. Yeah i am using new CSRF token on step 3 but after new csrf token generated Auth::user gets blank in my case

Comment: also i am getting 401 Unauthorized on step3 with new csrf token

Comment: after debugging i found that after step 2 session file get deleted from `storage\framework\sessions` and created new session file there,that is why `Auth::user()` get blank. How to solve this?

Comment: @MaheshSinghChouhan Are you sure you are using exact same domain all the time? You can use https vs non-https, www cs non-www ...

Comment: Hey @Marcin Nabialek, sorry for the late reply. Yeah i am using localhost:8000 each time but don't know why after login with new csrf token my old session file get deleted which had user details in it

Answer (score 0):

You may try this method `Auth::User()->id;`

Answer (score 0):

You can try `Auth::id()` to get the current user's id.

If you want all the details about logged in user then you can use `Auth::user()`.

By `Auth::user()` you can access all details about the user.

You can also log in from the controller by passing user id `Auth::login($user_id)`

And if you user `Auth::loginUsingId()` then you have to pass user id and `true` status for remember the details.

Like :`Auth:loginUsingId(user_id, true)`

---

For Example :

Get User's Id : `Auth::id()`

Get User's Name : `Auth::user()->name`

Get User's email : `Auth::user()->email`

etc....

Comment: after debugging i found that after step 2 session file get deleted from storage\framework\sessions and created new session file there,that is why Auth::user() get blank. 
So i use anything after that is blank because session file gets deleted which had user details in it

Comment: Hello @MaheshSinghChouhan, 
Did you check your **session.php** file in `config` folder, Or else you have to set the environment variable `SESSION_LIFETIME=120`, Here 120 is minutes and its default time.

Still, you found the same issue [visit](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/2314)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like its not an issue of CSRF at all.
When you create a new user, Like

```
$user = new App\User;
$user->username = $request->username;
...
...
$user->save();

Auth::loginUsingId($user->id);
```

Then place `dd(Auth::user()->id);` to check that user is logged in or not.

Let us know.